# min-width: none vs unset what is the proper apprach?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

What is the proper way to change it?

`minWidth: isSmall ? '12rem' : 'unset'`

or

`minWidth: isSmall ? '12rem' : 'none'`

There is nothing about it, but in some react applications I saw approach with 'none'
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: The `unset`  keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In most cases `none` is a safer solution if you want to reset the parameter.

Comment: @SimoneLungarella for value `unset`, `min-width` does not inherit vlaue from it's parent

Answer (score 2):

`none` is not a valid value for `min-width`, so you can use `unset`. Even you can use `auto` or `0` to actually not set anything.
`min-width` does not inherit it's value unless you explicitly define it's value to `inherit`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width), `none` is not a valid value for `min-width`. `Unset` however resets the property to its **inherited** value if it naturally inherits from its parent, otherwise it resets to its **initial** value. Instead of using `none`, you should be using `0` to set the `min-width` to 0 or `auto` so it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
minWidth: isSmall && '12rem'
```